# Overstayed in Canada for three months, will this affect student visa application to the UK?

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals, overstaying, student-visas

I was a student in Canada for 3 years. But I overstayed my stay for 3 months (wasn’t intentional). When I realised that I’m out of my permit I left the country by myself (didn’t get a deportation).

Now I got admission in Warwick University in the UK. Would this overstay issue in Canada be a problem for a UK student visa? Is it possible to get a visa refusal due to this overstay?

And I will definitely  not be hiding this fact from UKVI

Comment: 1st question: maybe. 2d question: maybe. The definitive way to find out if you can get a UK visa...is to _apply_ for a UK visa.

Answer (score 5):

Britain and Canada share immigration information under the Five Eyes treaty (along with the US, Australia and New Zealand). You should assume that the British authorities know about your overstay.

Accordingly, if you're asked you should declare it. Don't be tempted to try to cover it up. If the UK authorities know and you don't mention it you'll likely receive a lengthy ban for deception.

This will have an effect on any UK visa application. How much of an effect will depend on the details of the overstay and the nature of your application, amongst other things.

The only way to find out is to apply.